# istio incorrect handle of ingress backend path?

Tags: istio

Im trying to route my micro service via istio ingress with following configuration:

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: test
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "istio"
    spec:
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - path: /internal/v1.0/service
            backend:
              serviceName: sleep
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /external/v1.0/service
            backend:
              serviceName: sleep
              servicePort: 80
```

When I test this configuration I got 404 response from cluster.
It appears that istio threaten my path as regular expression

```
    → istioctl -n istio-shop get ingress-rule test-1-1
    destination: sleep.istio-shop.svc.cluster.local
    match:
      httpHeaders:
        uri:
          regex: /internal/v1.0/service
    route:
    - tags:
        servicePortNum: "80"
        tlsSecret: ""
```

The only way around I found was IS to get rid of "." in service API version and use some thing like this:

```
- path: /internal/v1/service
```

results in:

```
    → istioctl -n istio-shop get ingress-rule test-1-3
    destination: sleep.istio-shop.svc.cluster.local
    match:
      httpHeaders:
        uri:
          exact: /external/v1/service
    route:
    - tags:
        servicePortNum: "80"
        tlsSecret: ""
```

and

```
    - path: /internal/v1.*
```

results in:

```
        → istioctl -n istio-shop get ingress-rule test-1-4
        destination: sleep.istio-shop.svc.cluster.local
        match:
          httpHeaders:
            uri:
              prefix: /external/v1
        route:
        - tags:
            servicePortNum: "80"
            tlsSecret: ""
```

uri type was changed to "prefix" and "exact" from "regex"

I assume that dot "." is handled as a regex part not a regular sign.
Tried to escape it with "\" with no result.

Is that a bug? since  "/internal/v1.0/service" is not a regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed, Istio is trying to be smart when converting Ingress paths to Istio match config, but it looks like it's not quite smart enough in your case: https://github.com/istio/pilot/blob/master/adapter/config/ingress/conversion.go#L95

A simple "." character, alone (i.e., no following "*", for example) should not be mapped to a regex.

Please file a bug report in https://github.com/istio/issues/issues. Thanks